# UIImage 3Transform swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

how could i transform image to look like one from the image ?
just want to reach how that transformation works
for rotating im using an extention of UIImage, but thats all a got for now, just new in swift

```
public func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat, flip: Bool) -> UIImage {
    let radiansToDegrees: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
        return $0 * (180.0 / CGFloat(M_PI))
    }
    let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
        return $0 / 180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)
    }

    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))
    let t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(degrees));
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t
    let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
    let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width / 2.0, rotatedSize.height / 2.0);

    //   // Rotate the image context
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, degreesToRadians(degrees));

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    var yFlip: CGFloat

    if(flip){
        yFlip = CGFloat(-1.0)
    } else {
        yFlip = CGFloat(1.0)
    }

    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, yFlip, -1.0)
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-size.width / 2, -size.height / 2, size.width, size.height), CGImage)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

[image: dashboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use Core Animation with CATransform3D, and tweak the transform to give an impression of depth. What you do is to apply a small negative value (-1/200 is a good starting point) to the M34 component of the transformation matrix. You could ether do that to the layer of each of your views, or use a CATransformLayer on a super layer and then add the other images as sublayers of the transform layer.

This is tricky, fussy stuff. I haven't messed with it in a while so I don't remember the fine details any more, but that should be enough to get you started. I suggest searching on "iOS perspective", "M34" and "CATransformLayer" to find out more.

Comment: BTW, there is a very cool third party library called iCarousel that you could probably use to create the effect you are after. I'm not sure it could do a matrix like that though. You might have to stack 3 carousels on top of each other.